# How to add some form of visual focus to an image map's Area elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

hoping for a little steer here

A project has come up at work, we have a 'Road Map' image that visually depicts a user journey through a service. At present, the image has a null Alt attribute, as all of the text within the image is on the page and the image is merely eye-candy.

Some stakeholders would like the functionality to touch or click a part of the image then be taken to the heading with the corresponding ID. Pretty simple to implement, with  and <area(s)>.

This is technically permissible in WCAG 2.1 AA, however, sighted keyboard users would not get the benefit of knowing where they were, in the tab order. A screen reader user would be fine, as with proper Alt text on the  and <area(s)> it would act just like a table of contents.

The bounding rect, cannot be styled with CSS (at least not in a way I know of) and I'm not going to implement something that will create confusion for any user.

It would appear WCAG 2.0 required a title attribute and WCAG 2.1 does not, which makes sense, as that is only available to mouse users and makes links etc more verbose to screen readers.

I'll stop waffling and get to the point. What would my options be, for providing some kind of visible focus, especially for sighted keyboard users?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Image maps are old technology, update to SVG and each element is individually selectable

Comment: By "bounding rect" do you mean the focus indicator, or something else?

Comment: @Josh No, the rectangle that contains the hit area for the links within the map, is what I meant for bounding rect. But I would like to be able to add a focus indicator to this, so keyboard users know where they are, but it doesn't look possible using image maps

Comment: @Paulie_D it does appear SVG is likely the best way to achieve this, I'll need to look a little deeper into it first. I'll try to find some resources to read.

Comment: Don't know how or if the SVG route worked out, but Canvas can fairly easily provide a border to indicate focus.  Put a canvas over the image.  Attach mouseover and mouseout handlers to the AREA elements.  On a mouseover, get the area shape (rect, poly, circle) and coords property values.  Use those to draw a rect, poly or circle.  On a mouseout, do exactly the same but set the globalCompositeOperation to "xor" (rather than the default "source-over").  Using xor means the line will be transparent.  It's basically an eraser.